# Why does "sattsehen" take accusative "mich", not dative "mir"? Even though it is not "me" that I'm looking at?

Tags: grammatical-case

Why "mich"?

> Ich kann **mich** daran gar nicht **sattsehen**.

Instead of,

> Ich kann **mir** daran gar nicht **sattsehen**.

The thing I'm looking at is something meant by "daran", so doesn't accusative "mich" make it sound like "I'm looking at myself"?

My confusion comes from a similar construct,

> **mir** etwas **ansehen**

Comment: Searching a "why" answer for syntax phenomena is usually rather pointless. There is no actual logic behind it.  Just accept that the expression is as it is.

Answer (score 8):

Don't concentrate that much on **sehen**, rather on the meaning of **satt** when trying to make sense of **sattsehen**. That's crucial for understanding why the accusative is correct here.

The [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sattsehen) gives the following meaning for **sattsehen**:

> sich etwas so oft, so lange ansehen, dass es einem reicht

[Langenscheidt](https://de.langenscheidt.com/deutsch-englisch/sattsehen) gives the following possible translation:

> Not to be able to see enough of

What you are looking at is **daran**.

And your action (**sattsehen**) does have an effect on someone, namely **you**. Hence it's accusative (*Wen oder Was?* -> *mich*. *Wen sehe ich satt? Mich!*).

**You** cannot look at *daran* for so long, that **you** have enough of doing so. You are not able to see enough of *daran*.

*Satt* can [mean](https://de.langenscheidt.com/deutsch-englisch/satt) *full up*, *satisfied*, *satiated*. It's usually used when you ate enough and now cannot eat more. (as guidot noted in a comment, *sattessen* has the same accusative construction).

In your example, it's a bit complicated because it's a kind of double negation:

- *Sattsehen* -> You are satiated. You can *not* see more of it.
- Whatever *daran* is, you can *not* see enough of it. *Sattsehen* is negated.

Comment: *Sattsehen* is pretty similar to *sattessen*, it's the same *mich* accusative construction.

Comment: @guidot, very good point :) After all when I say "Ich esse mich satt", I'm usually not eating myself.

Answer (score 6):

First, note the formal difference: *etwas ansehen* already has an accusative object. Therefore, if another nominal object is to appear, it must be in the dative. (There is only a handful of exceptions to this rule.)

Second, the pattern that builds *sattsehen* is productive. The adjective is interpreted as a [resultative predicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultative) pertaining to the single object, which is in the accusative. The accusative is to be expected in that the object is undergoing a change of state, with the resultant state being described by the adjective. In the case of ***sich*** **satt**sehen, think *seeing so much of something that **you** have become **satiated*** (i.e. don't want to look at it any further). Further examples:

> Ich habe **mich müde** gelaufen.
>   "I walked so much that I am tired now."
>
> Er hat **sich schwarz**geärgert.
>   *Lit.* "He was so angry that he is now black.", *i.e.* "He got really angry."
>
> Sie hat **sich warm**geredet.
>   *Lit.* "She has talked so much that she is now warmed-up."
>
> Man hat **ihn grün und blau** geschlagen.
>    "They hit him until he was black and blue."
>
> Es hat schon wieder jemand **eine Katze tot**gefahren.
>   *Lit.* "Someone drove a cat dead again.", *i.e.* "Someone ran over a cat again."

The predicative doesn't need to be an adjective.

> Sie hat **sich in Fahrt/Rage** geredet. *(similar to the third example above)*

Note that whether the object is reflexive or not is dictated by plausibility. So although *sattsehen* is always reflexive, *müde laufen* does not need to be:

> Die Mannschaft hat **den Gegner müde** gelaufen.
>   "The team ran their opponent ragged."

*Sattsehen* likes to appear in the idiom *sich (an etwas) nicht sattsehen können*.

> Die Landschaft war so schön, daß man sich an ihr nicht sattsehen konnte.
>   "The landscape was so beautiful that you couldn't get enough of it."

Comment: Thank you so much. In the following sentence though, using dative "dir" is wrong, right? "Du solltest (**dir**) deine Hoffnungen lieber nicht all zu hoch **ansetzen**."

Comment: @Dasshoes I think it's not customary. German allows adding datives pretty freely (grammars literally talk about *freie Dative*), therefore the sentence sounds more unusual than plain wrong.

Comment: Ich lach mich schlapp

Comment: _Sich_ is the same in the dative as in the accusative. So it is a bad pronoun to use in examples to show the use of the accusative!

Comment: @TonyK OP already knows it's an accusative. Also, three examples have an unambiguous accusative?

Comment: "Du solltest (dir) deine Hoffnungen lieber nicht all zu hoch ansetzen." is fine. "deine Hoffnungen" is already accusative, so "dir" is dative. We can modify the sentence to make it accusative if we remove the other one: "Du solltest dich nicht so hoch setzen."

Answer (score 3):

The "mich" part just refers to the fact that one is the actor himself e.g. you are the one who does the looking.
Compare to the term "sich erinnern" (to remember) -> "ich erinnere mich" does not mean 'I remember me', but rather that I am the one remembering something/someone

So in the case of "mich sattsehen" the mich is not ruled by the act of looking, but by the sating of the desire to look at someting :)
As such it roughly transcribes as 'I sate myself (accusative) by looking at sth.'

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion is about **daran**. It's very different from *etwas*, because it replaces a prepositional object or adverbial. That's because of the built-in preposition *an*:

> Ich kann mich **daran** gar nicht sattsehen.
>
> Ich kann mich **an (so) etwas** gar nicht sattsehen.

In contrary, a plain *etwas* is indeed an accusative object.

> "Ich kann mir **etwas** gar nicht sattsehen."
>
> Ich kann mir **etwas** gar nicht ansehen.

In contrary to *ansehen*, the accusative object of *sattsehen* isn't the object ogled at however, but the thing or person which experiences the effect. That's the common use for the accusative object.

> Ich kann **mich** gar nicht sattsehen.

This is similar with German verbs which take two accusative objects

> Sie lehrt **mich** etwas Neues.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a classical German construct of [*sich* + **verb**](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/verbs/reflexive-verbs). That's the reason why it conjugates the way you describe.

Take for example *sich* + **freuen** (to be happy):

The forms are:

- ich **freue** *mich*
- du **freust** *dich*
- er/sie/es **freut** *sich*
- wir **freuen** *uns*
- ihr **freut** *euch*
- sie **freuen** *sich*

Similarly, in your sentence the construct is *sich* + **sattsehen** (to be satisfied watching). However, the Grammar slightly changes because **sattsehen** is a [separable verb](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb). Therefore:

- ich **sehe** *mich* **satt**
- du **siehst** *dich* **satt**
- er/sie/es **sieht** *sich* **satt**
- wir **sehen** *uns* **satt**
- ihr **seht** *euch* **satt**
- sie **sehen** *sich* **satt**

This can be further extended by the form *sich* an etwas/jemand **sattsehen** (to be satisfied watching something/someone). With this, you are able to specify what you are watching. For example:

- ich **sehe** *mich* daran **satt**
- ...

However, for a person this might be:

- ich **sehe** *mich* an dir **satt**
- ich **sehe** *mich* an ihr/ihm **satt**
- ...

Or for a narcissist:

- ich **sehe** *mich* an mir **satt**

The above might be the the reason for your confusion. These sentences look quite similar, but are in fact very different in meaning.

Last but not least, you have a negation with *können* in your sentence:

- Ich *kann* *mich* [...] nicht **sattsehen**.

This changes the Grammar to the way *können* works. (**sattsehen** is no longer separated, as it is not the predicate in this sentence.) Furthermore, the meaning switches from: `I'm satisfied watching [...].` to `I cannot stop watching [...] (satisfiedly).`

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to look at it is that "sattsehen" doesn't so much come from "sehen" but is more related to "gewöhnen". When you get used to the sight of something extraordinary, you can say this: "Ich habe mich daran gewöhnt, es zu sehen." Or you can say the following: "Ich habe mich daran sattgesehen."

You probably shouldn't look for logical consistency in any human language, after all, we've failed to describe them mathematically, no matter which brilliant minds tried just that. It's the same in English. The only thing we can do is make it easier for ourselves to remember the quirks.